# How do i insert non english into sql db using android studio?

Tags: android, sql-server

I am developing an app in this i want to use English and Marathi both langauges but here my problem is when i am inserting marathi text then in the sql db it shows ???? not a proper text.

Following is my code please suggest me How do i insert marathi text in the sql db? When i am inserting english text then shows proper result but when inserting marathi text it shows ?????.

Please give me suggestion.

```
//activity

    public class UserProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

            private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
            private Toolbar toolbar;
            NavigationView navigationView;
            PagerAdapter adapter;
            TextView edMob;
            EditText edFname, edName, edSname, edBdate, edMob1, edAddress, edArea;
            Button btnMyprofile, btnOurservices, btnCallservices, btnAnycomplaint, btnSave, btnMarathi, btnEnglish;
            RadioButton rbMale, rbFemale, rbGender;
            RadioGroup rgSex, rgGender;
            Calendar myCalendar;
            private static ViewPager mPager;
            private static int currentPage = 0;

            JSONArray user = null;
            private static String url1 = null;

            private static final String TAG_USER = "Registration";
            private static final String TAG_RID = "regid";
            private static final String TAG_FNAME = "fname";
            private static final String TAG_MNAME = "mname";
            private static final String TAG_LNAME = "lname";
            private static final String TAG_GENDER = "gender";
            private static final String TAG_DOB = "dob";
            private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "emailid";
            private static final String TAG_CNO = "contactno";
            private static final String TAG_AREA = "areaname";
            private static final String TAG_ADDRESS = "flatnoapt";
            private static final String TAG_UNPW = "userpwd";
            private static final String TAG_OTPNO = "otpno";
            private static final String TAG_ISV = "isverified";
            private static final String TAG_GCMT = "gcmtoken";
            private static final String TAG_ECODE = "error_code";
            private static final String TAG_EMSG = "error_message";

            private boolean isLoggedIn = false;
            SessionManagement session;
            Locale myLocale;

            private String TAG = UserProfileActivity.class.getSimpleName();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);

                toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                TextView toolbarTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                toolbarTitle.setText("User Profile");
                toolbar.setTitleMarginBottom(50);

                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

                edFname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edFname);
                edName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edName);
                edSname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edSname);
                edArea = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edArea);
                edAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edAddress);
                edBdate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edBdate);
                edMob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edMob);

                rgSex = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgSex);

                rbMale = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
                rbFemale= (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);

                btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
                btnEnglish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEnglish);
                btnMarathi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnMarathi);

                session = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SessionManagement.PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                isLoggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SessionManagement.IS_LOGIN, false);
                String email = sharedPreferences.getString(SessionManagement.KEY_SESSIONID, "Not Available");

                url1 = "http://test/api/getregister?contactno="+email;

                if(isLoggedIn){
                    new JSONParse().execute();
                }

                //bday date
                edBdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                                updateLabel();
                            }
                        };

                        new DatePickerDialog(UserProfileActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                    }
                });


                btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (checkValidation()) {

                            int selectedIdGender = rgSex.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            rbGender = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedIdGender);

                            // Get the values given in EditText fields
                            String fname1 = edName.getText().toString();
                            String lname1 = edSname.getText().toString();
                            String mname1 = edFname.getText().toString();
                            String dob = edBdate.getText().toString();
                            String contactno1 = edMob.getText().toString();
                            String areaname1 = edArea.getText().toString();
                            String flatnoapt1 = edAddress.getText().toString();
                            String sex = rbGender.getText().toString();
                            String deviceid = null;
                            String emailid= null;
                            String userpwd=null;
                            String otpno=null;
                            String isverified=null;
                            String gcmtoken=null;

                            String gender= null;
                            if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")){
                                gender= String.valueOf(0);
                            }else if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")){
                                gender= String.valueOf(1);
                            }

                            try {
                                String fname = URLEncoder.encode(fname1, "utf-8");
                                String lname = URLEncoder.encode(lname1, "utf-8");
                                String mname = URLEncoder.encode(mname1, "utf-8");
                                String areaname = URLEncoder.encode(areaname1, "utf-8");
                                String flatnoapt = URLEncoder.encode(flatnoapt1, "utf-8");
                                String contactno = URLEncoder.encode(contactno1, "utf-8");

                                System.out.println("Given Name :" + fname + " Given password is :" + lname);
                                connectWithHttpGet(fname, mname, lname, gender, dob, emailid, contactno, areaname, flatnoapt, userpwd, otpno, isverified, gcmtoken);

                                Intent i= new Intent(UserProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);

                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "Please Fill the fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


          private void connectWithHttpGet(String fname, String mname, String lname, String gender, String dob, String emailid, String contactno, String areaname, String flatnoapt, String userpwd, String otpno, String isverified, String gcmtoken){
            class HttpGetAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                        String paramFname = params[0];
                        String paramMname = params[1];
                        String paramLname = params[2];
                        String paramGender = params[3];
                        String paramBirthdate = params[4];
                        String paramEmail = params[5];
                        String paramMobile = params[6];
                        String paramArea = params[7];
                        String paramAddress = params[8];
                        String paramUnpw = params[9];
                        String paramOtpno = params[10];
                        String paramIsverified = params[11];
                        String paramGcmtoken = params[12];

                        System.out.println("userID" + paramFname + " last name is :" + paramLname + "birthdate:" + paramBirthdate);

                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://test/api/Updateregister?fname="+paramFname+
                                "&mname="+ paramMname+
                                "&lname="+paramLname+
                                "&gender="+paramGender+
                                "&dob="+paramBirthdate+
                                "&emailid="+null+
                                "&contactno="+paramMobile+
                                "&areaname="+paramArea+
                                "&flatnoapt="+paramAddress+
                                "&userpwd="+null+
                                "&otpno="+null+
                                "&isverified="+false+
                                "&gcmtoken="+null);

                        try {
                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                            System.out.println("httpResponse// getEntity() ; obtains the message entity of this response");

                            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                        //    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");//
                            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            String bufferedStrChunk = null;

                            while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
                            }

                            System.out.println("Returninge of doInBackground :" + stringBuilder.toString());
                            return stringBuilder.toString();
                        } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                            System.out.println("Exceptionrates caz of httpResponse :" + cpe);
                            cpe.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            System.out.println("Secondption generates caz of httpResponse :" + ioe);
                            ioe.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                        super.onPostExecute(result);
                        System.out.println("httpResponse :" + result);

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                            JSONArray login = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Registration");
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = login.getJSONObject(0);

                            String responsetypes = jsonObject1.optString("error_code");
                            String message = jsonObject1.getString("error_message");

                           if (TextUtils.equals(responsetypes, "Success")) {
                             Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } else if (TextUtils.equals(responsetypes, "Failure")) {
                                Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            HttpGetAsyncTask httpGetAsyncTask = new HttpGetAsyncTask();
            //  httpGetAsyncTask.execute(firstname, middlename, lastname, gender, birthdate, mobile, area, address);
            httpGetAsyncTask.execute(fname, mname, lname, gender, dob, emailid, contactno, areaname, flatnoapt, userpwd, otpno, isverified, gcmtoken);
            }

            private void updateLabel() {
                String myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"; //In which you need put here
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                edBdate.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    // action with ID action_refresh was selected
                    case android.R.id.home:
                        Intent i8 = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        i8.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i8);
                        finish();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

            private boolean checkValidation() {
                boolean ret = true;
                if (!Validation.hasText(edFname)) ret = false;
                if (!Validation.hasText(edSname)) ret = false;
                if (!Validation.hasText(edName)) ret = false;
                //  if (!Validation.isEmailAddress(ed, true)) ret = false;
                if (!Validation.isBirthDate(edBdate, true)) ret = false;
                if (!Validation.hasText(edAddress)) ret = false;
                if (!Validation.hasText(edArea)) ret = false;
              //  if (!Validation.isPhoneNumber(edMob, true)) ret = false;
                return ret;
            }


            //for get details
            private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
                private ProgressDialog pDialog;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserProfileActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
                    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                    // Getting JSON from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);
                    Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + json);

                    return json;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    try {

                        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
                        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

                        String rid = c.getString(TAG_RID);
                        String fname = c.getString(TAG_FNAME);
                        String mname = c.getString(TAG_MNAME);
                        String lname = c.getString(TAG_LNAME);
                        String gender = c.getString(TAG_GENDER);
                        String dob = c.getString(TAG_DOB);
                        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                        String contact = c.getString(TAG_CNO);
                        String area = c.getString(TAG_AREA);
                        String adddress = c.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                        String unpw = c.getString(TAG_UNPW);
                        String otpno = c.getString(TAG_OTPNO);
                        String isv = c.getString(TAG_ISV);
                        String gcmt = c.getString(TAG_GCMT);
                        String ecode = c.getString(TAG_ECODE);
                        String emsg = c.getString(TAG_EMSG);

                        //Set JSON Data in TextView
                        edName.setText(fname);
                        edFname.setText(mname);
                        edSname.setText(lname);
                        edArea.setText(area);
                        edAddress.setText(adddress);
                        edMob.setText(contact);
                        edBdate.setText(dob);

                        if(gender.contains("0"))
                        {
                            rbMale.setChecked(true);
                            rbFemale.setChecked(false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            rbMale.setChecked(false);
                            rbFemale.setChecked(true);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: sounds like the application is not using unicode to show/edit the values

Comment: using android studio

Comment: I guess the columns in your database are of type `varchar`, change them to `nvarchar`

Comment: In the backend already declare nvarchar datatype

Comment: in that case the application does not uses `unicode`. I have no knowledge of android studio, maybe you need different type then `string` ?

Comment: in code i am uses encode utf-8 for non english text but its not reflected and doesnot show result in marathi text

Comment: Use the profiler from SSMS to see the update/insert commands send to your database. My guess is the text values are already broken there. Somewhere in your application you loose unicode

Comment: `String message = etEnterMsg.getText().toString().trim();`   `String dataSave=StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(message);` use this Escape class  of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 . pass `dataSave` String to Database.

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel   ok i will try to pass tring like above format

Comment: gives error at StringEscapeUtils

Comment: add in app level gradle `compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'`

Comment: Response from url: {"Registration":[{"otpno":"null","userpwd":"null","mname":"?? ","regid":0,"lname":"??","areaname":"xjj","gcmtoken":"null","error_code":"0","emailid":"null","flatnoapt":"hzhz","error_message":"success","dob":"2017-11-20","gender":1,"isverified":false,"contactno":"1232456589","fname":"?"}]}

Comment: this is my response it shows ?? instead of marathi text

Comment: simplest idea i can give you that convert your non english text into hex and insert into sql. after than you want to get back from sqlite, de-hex the string

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar please give me example in code format

Comment: try to set back in TextView you have to use `tvFname.setText(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(jsonResponse.getString("fname"));`

Comment: @KuLdipPaTel and how to insert marathi text into sql db?

Comment: this one work with response ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode your non-english into UTF-8 for insertion and later on decode it when you will retrieve it from database. Try the follow code:

```
// Sending side
byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text = new String(data, "UTF-8");
```